# How do I loop through a column in a Grid View and access a specific cell if the value of that cell is equal to a value I am looking for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have a GridView that is populated with data from a database. I want to loop through a specific column in the GridView and if a cell in the column contains a certain value then I want to perform another action. However I dunno how to loop through the column.

Comment: Don't loop the cells, loop the source data!

Comment: thanks, but Im not sure how to do that